# Session Authentiction not working with django and vuejs

Tags: django, vue.js

I am getting the csrf token and i am using axios to send a get request to the rest api. 
when i set the CSRF token and try to get the data, i get a 403 forbidden error.

```
axios.get("my-api-url",{

header:{

'X-CSRFTOKEN': csrftoken

}
})
.then(res -> console.log(res))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```